# Can't find wine1.6.2 after adding a ppa

Tags: apt, software-installation, wine, ppa

I am installing wine 1.6.2 on Ubuntu 12.04, following this link  http://www.tecmint.com/install-wine-on-ubuntu-and-linux-mint/

> Installation of Wine 1.6.2 To install Wine, open the terminal by
>   hitting ‘CTRL + ALT + T‘ from the desktop and run the following
>   commands one-by-one on the terminal.
>
> ```
> $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
> $ sudo apt-get update
> $ sudo apt-get install wine1.6
> $ sudo apt-get install winetricks
> ```

But

```
$ sudo apt-get install wine1.6
[sudo] password for tim: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
wine1.6 is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgnutlsxx27 libkadm5clnt-mit8 libgpg-error-dev comerr-dev libgcrypt11-dev dh-apparmor libkrb5-dev libldap2-dev libgssrpc4
  krb5-multidev libgnutls-openssl27 libkadm5srv-mit8 libkdb5-6 libkms1 libidn11-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.

$ wine --version
wine-1.6.1

$ whereis wine
wine: /usr/bin/wine /usr/bin/X11/wine /usr/share/wine /usr/share/man/man1/wine.1.gz
```

Comment: I have checked this ppa and  Wine 1.6.2  is not available on this ppa. you can use `apt-cache policy wine` to check available wine version. it should show `wine  1:1.7.18-0ubuntu1` for ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Is it 1.7.18 version? I saw on wine website, that the latest stable version is 1.6.2. shall I install 1.7.18?

Comment: According to [WineHQ](https://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu)  1.7 packages here are beta packages.stable 1.6 Wine version works for you, then you may not want to use these beta packages.

Answer (score 1):

The wine ppa tends to have the latest version and work on the latest Ubuntu versions. If you look at the wine ppa right now in [Wine PPA for 12.04](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=precise) you will noticed the last update for the 1.6.x was the 1.6.1, or to be more precise, the 1:1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1

You will also noticed that it offers that 1.7.x versions but up to 1.7.18, when on 14.04 it offers the 1.7.27 which is the latest version. I recommend jumping to either a new version of Ubuntu (14.04 or the next 14.10 when it comes out) to have the latest wine version. I also recommend removing 1.6.x and installing 1.7 (or 1.8 when it comes out), since there are more than 500+ enhancements compared to 1.6.x

Of course, in the case you want to have the latest wine. If not you can stay in 12.04 and stick with either the current 1.6.x or jump to 1.7.